# getting null after JSON request parsing if field contains incompatable types

Tags: java, json, rest

I have a JSON request like this,

```
"details" : {
     "name" : "vinay",
     "amount" : "123"
}
```

In java amount field is BigDecimal.

suppose in my request if the amount field gets like this

```
"details" : {
     "name" : "vinay",
     "amount" : "abc"
}
```

in java amount field is getting null after parsing.
How to handle this type of request while JSON parsing or any other solutions?

Comment: [No "_Thanks"_, it's not necessary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) and please [format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code as code.

Comment: first why do you accept amount as string, it either be double or float.

Comment: Can i use MessagBodyReader of REST ? will it work in this case ??

Comment: Your question implies, that your problem is the parsing of JSON, now you are talking about a MessageBodyReader from REST API. I do not understand how this connects to your question... could you make this clear?

Answer (score 0):

Using `org.json.*` library I would use the `JSONObject.getBigDecimal()` method in order to extract the value as BigDecimal.

Answer (score -1):

JSON by default converts everything to string. we need to parse it manually in java. You can simply do isNumeric check in Java.

Comment: No, JSON does not.